# bounded function $f$ such that $f(f(a)f(b)) = f(a b)$ and $ f(f(a)+f(b)) = f(a+b)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am trying to find a function $f$ which is bounded by some integer $M$ such that for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that :

$f(f(a)+f(b))=f(a+b)$ and $ f(f(a)f(b)) = f(a b)$, first i thought about the $mod$ function meaning about floor and fractional part functions and it holds that $f(f(a)+f(b)) = f(a+b)$ but it does not hold for real numbers in multiplication, also $f(x)=x$ work for both but it is not bounded.

Does such function exist ?

Edit : I was thinking about $f(f(a)+f(b)) = f(a+b)$ and $ f(f(a)f(b))=f(a)f(b)$ like the idea of $mod$ with integers, for example $ (2*4) \mod 7 = 1$ and $ ((2 \mod 7) * (4 \mod 7)) \mod 7 =1 $

Examples and why they don't work :

1. $f(x)=x$ satisfy the conditions $f(a+b)=f(f(a)+f(b))$ and $f(a b) = f(f(a)f(b))$ but $f$ is not Bounded
2. $f(x)= x \mod M$ is Bounded and satisfy the condition $ f(a+b) =f(f(a)+f(b))$ but fails the condition $ f(a b) =f(f(a) f(b))$
3. $ f(x) = e^{2 \pi i x}$ is Bounded and satisfy the condition $ f(a b) =f(f(a) f(b))$ but fails the condition $ f(a +b) =f(f(a)+ f(b))$

Comment: We get $f(n)=nf(1)$ and so $f$ is bounded only if $f(1)=0$. But then $f=0$.

Comment: @lhf you are right but i was thinking about $f(f(a)+f(b)) = f(a+b)$ and $ f(f(a)f(b))=f(a)f(b)$ like the idea of $mod$ with integers, for example $ (2*4) \mod 7 = 1$ and $ ((2 \mod 7) * (4 \mod 7)) \mod 7 =1 $

Comment: Radically changing the question after people have posted comments and answers is a bad idea.  If you had intended to ask a different question, delete this post and post a new one.

Comment: @lhf,lulu noted for future questions

Comment: Any constant function works.

Comment: Why do you say that $2.$ is failling for multiplication ?

Comment: @zwim $ f(x) = x \mod 3$ then $ f(\sqrt{15} \sqrt{12}) = 1.41641 \not=0.405153 = f(f(\sqrt{12} )f(\sqrt{15}))  $

Comment: Ah yes, then maybe $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor\pmod M$ or something in this vein could be tested.